# Simple ICMP DoS attack example with cmd on Windows 10 crashing the attacker's computer?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, wireshark, denial-of-service

I had to make a simple batch file as an assignment in which I had to attack another PC on the same network by a ICMP DoS attack and analyze the traffic using Wire-Shark. Here the code which I used:

attack.bat:

```
:A
start ping.bat
goto A
```

ping.bat:

```
ping 192.168.1.100 -t -l 65500
```

It was successful as this created a lot of cmd consoles which were continuously pinging the victim PC and this obviously had a effect on the network traffic and also there was an observable load on the victim PC. Here both, the attacker as well as the victim PC both were 4th generation i3 with 4gb of RAM and were running on Windows 8.1

When I tried doing exactly same on my own computer which runs Windows 10 and overall more updated specs (Intel i5 5th gen, 8gb RAM, cache size is bigger etc.) also much better than the PC I tried in college, except the clock rate (3.5 vs 2.7GHz), the attacking computer literally hanged within a minute which resulted into initial increase in traffic but later stopped receiving any because of the attacker PC's crash.

What can be the possible reason for it? Is it a Windows 10 issue or something I'm doing wrong the second time?

Comment: my guess is that this implementation of ping doesn't do well with non-responsive echo requests when there are large volumes of them pending, which corrupted your IP stack, just a completely unsubstantiated hunch. personally I'm really suprised you guys are doing practical testing with an attack that old (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_of_death). My guess is the windows 8.1 machines had their firewall loosened in relation to fragment reassembly of ICMP traffic, to allow the attack to work, which probably results in response from echo.

Comment: The faster you go the harder you hit the wall.  A car accident at 10mph is minor, but at 100 everyone dies.  The attacker hangs because the fast computer can respond to way more packets per second than a slower computer.

Answer (score 1):

```
:A
start ping.bat
goto A
```

This code would flood the attacking computer with CMD tabs until the attacking computer's CPU would crash under stress with so many processes being created and running. More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb